# Filter date, and add blank rows between different time slots

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula, google-sheets-dates

I'm trying to build a reservations spreadsheet for my friend's restaurant where she can input on monthly sheets as resos come in, then see a filtered, sorted summary of any selected day.

[Here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1qnTwJYNQWB-svxKQO4pLyre7Ce6TiGTzNQKdwHdB3sU/edit?usp=sharing) is a copy of the sheet I have so far (with false resos).

**Daily Overview**: this is as far as I've managed to get. In cell A6 I'm able to filter the data from the ***hide_feed*** tab by the date selected in cell A1, but I'm not able to have the formula insert blank rows to group the times, as demonstrated in ***Daily Overview_Desired Outcome***

**Date Range**: same issue here, in A6 I'm able to filter by date range (selected in A1,B1), but would like there to be a blank row between each date in column A, as demonstrated in ***Date Range_Desired Outcome***

PLEASE HELP! I've tried everything!

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Comment: Exact copy of [Filter date, and add blank rows between different time slots](https://support.google.com/docs/thread/163988692) that has an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom formula filters to achieve this.

 In the filter menu, go to *Filter by condition > Custom formula is* ...

#### Daily Overview:

E.g. to filter for 6:30 pm and later, keeping blank rows.

 `=(A6>=TIME(18,30,0))+(A6="")`

 **You'll need to format column A as Time for the formula to work.*

#### Date Range:

E.g. to filter for 5/21/2022 onwards, keeping blank rows.

 `=(A6>=DATE(2022,5,21))+(A6="")`

[image]
  
[image]